# Change namespace class autoload to manual require_once PHP

Tags: php

I want to use namespaces class to manual one without using autoload.php to be included. Because I don't want to use all function the class.

I am using this project https://github.com/codenix-sv/coingecko-api to get it's function in my php function.

In the example of using is like this

```
use Codenixsv\CoinGeckoApi\CoinGeckoClient;

$client = new CoinGeckoClient();

$data = $client->ping();
```

But I want to change it to require_once. So I put all src folder in my php folder and create this to call the function

```
require_once 'libs/Api/CoinGeckoClient.php';
$client = new Codenixsv\CoinGeckoApi\CoinGeckoClient;

$data = $client->simple();
```

First I got this error when trying to access the page.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\te.st\libs\Api\CoinGeckoClient.php:35

Then I try to remove the line "use GuzzleHttp\Client" in CoinGeckoClient.php file.
And got with this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Codenixsv\CoinGeckoApi\Client' not
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs\te.st\libs\Api\CoinGeckoClient.php:35

Is there any way to just use the "simple" function of coingecko only in my php file.

> https://github.com/codenix-sv/coingecko-api/blob/master/src/Api/Simple.php

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use all of the functions?  It can sometimes take more effort to work out all of the dependencies than it's worth.

Comment: Because I just want to convert the price only, no need all function.

Comment: Now I'm trying to use the full function with autoload.php seems that the same error occur when trying to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I fix this.
load in composer.json like

```
{
    "require": {
      "codenix-sv/coingecko-api": "^1.0",
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
    }
}
```

then do composer update in command window.

In my php file. make sure

> use Codenixsv\CoinGeckoApi\CoinGeckoClient;

is placed in top of file. Then do the rest.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

That package is prepared to works with composer.
Composer delivered autoloader, to make you work simplier.

If you remove `use GuzzleHttp\Client` line from `CoinGeckoClient.php`, there will be no way to send request to the server.

The best option is include composer autoload in your project file, it means you should:

1. Create composer.json file for you project
2. Add required library dependency using command: `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`
3. Add require library dependency using command: `composer require codenix-sv/coingecko-api`
4. Inside your project file add folowing line:

   ```
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');

   use Codenixsv\CoinGeckoApi\CoinGeckoClient;

   $client = new CoinGeckoClient();
   $data = $client->ping();
   ```

In other way, that will be necessarily to import all files manually. And of course, you haven't to forget about imports for Guzzle client.

Comment: I'm using your suggest and finish with this error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE). I'm using PHP 7.3 in xampp.

Comment: Ok, just a little letter mistake. Please try again. I fixed it and add Guzzle as also required library.